# MQTT-SN over Serial Wire (Bluetooth, CAN, RS485, ...)

Tags: bluetooth, mqtt

I found this Answer [RSMB MQTT-SN & Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483943/rsmb-mqtt-sn-bluetooth/34175195#34175195), but I am not sure if this is really the correct answer at all.

So a second Question - I am new to Stackoverflow so I cannot comment directly.

...

Are you sure that a forwarder is really needed here? I read the MQTT-SN spec and for me it looks like MQTT-SN is for UDP and UDP is connectionless. So I think it is possible so simulate UDP over serial for one point to point connection.

So why not...

mqtt-sn client---serial-->> any radio <<--serial---mqtt-sn serial brigdge

And on the MQTT-SN serial bridge side I can also run a Gateway which connects to a real MQTT broker of my choice.

I read that out from figure 1 in the specs. I do not clearly understand what´s the benefit of a forwarder is? And when should someone use it and so on ...

thanks. Mathias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forwarder encapsulates the address on the radio network of the client, so the broker can reply to the right client when there is more than one client.

Comment: So you mean if I implement an MQTT-SN switch client as an example. And the client publishes "switch/state/ON" or "switch/state/OFF" then over a forwarder I can handle which switch comes from which client - right?

Comment: No, more to do with MQTT-SN messages that generate a response, such as topic registration. If you are using a fixed set of predefined topic ids then a simple bridge could work (except the spec recomends that topic ids are specific to each client)

Comment: Okay I hope i will find out what you mean exact. I will have a look into that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730894/how-to-configure-mqtt-sn-topic-ids-in-rsmb fork. Maybe I will find the answer there for me. Thanks.